# HTML File src/link file paths not working

Tags: html, path

I have an html file system that currently goes like this:

```
root:
    index.html
    |-css
       -simple-sidebar.css
    |-vendor:
       |-bootstrap:
          |-css:
             -bootstrap.min.css
          |js:
             -bootstrapp.bundle.js
       |-jquery
          -jquery.min.js
```

which works perfectly using the file paths:

```
 <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

however, when i put all of the files into a folder called static, and index.html in a folder called templates:

```
 root:
        |-templates:
            -index.html
        |-static
            |-css:
               -simple-sidebar.css
            |-vendor:
               |-bootstrap:
                  |-css:
                     -bootstrap.min.css
                  |js:
                     -bootstrapp.bundle.js
               |-jquery
                  -jquery.min.js
```

with these file paths:

```
<link href  ="/static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/static/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
```

And the files fail to load, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding ".." in front of the paths

Comment: it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on my comment:

The paths needed to have `../` in front of them instead of just `/`.

Placing `../` in front of a path lets you go up *one* level in the folder structure.
You can also use it multiple times in succession to go up multiple levels.
For example, `../../` would go up *two* levels, `../../../` would go up three levels, etc.